# How to enable Bing's "Chat with Video" feature?

Tags: video, bing

There was a 'Chat with Video' feature on Bing that no longer appears in my account/region.
**It allowed one to talk to a GPT instance that is knowledgeable on the topic of the video.**
How do I enable this feature again?

I thought maybe this feature moved and asked bing chat on edge sidebar and it said: "*I’m sorry, but I don’t have the ability to analyze or discuss the contents of videos. I can provide information on a wide range of topics, answer questions, and even generate creative content like stories and poems. However, video analysis is beyond my current capabilities.*"
This was frustrating since this feature was available for a long while.

How can I enable this feature back?

Comment: Please provide more details about Bing's Chat with video feature that you are referring to as we don't have previous questions about such a feature. I'm asking because you might be confused and referring to a built-in feature, i.e., something added through a Bing plug-in or a web browser extension. It might also be possible that you are being confused by a feature that you have seen on another Generative AI.